# definition of a map from $CP^1$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry

I think this is a very easy question, but I've got problems understanding how the function in the second exercise of this pdf (that I found online on google and I wanted to try in order to improve my math-skills) is defined:

[Link to the pdf](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=30&ved=0CIgBEBYwCTgU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uwo.ca%2F~masoud%2Ffiles%2FRSAssign2.pdf&ei=L-PSUoq-DcT4ygO7xYD4Ag&usg=AFQjCNEDoJSsMDPejys0ocs1zM7-kfdb2A&sig2=cQUjf83xmEFiC35Scsj_Cw&bvm=bv.59026428,d.Yms)

In my understanding $CP^1$ is the set $C^2 \setminus (0,0)$ modulo the equivalence relation $(z_1,z_2) \sim (w_1,w_2)$ if there is $\lambda \ne 0$ such that $w_i=\lambda z_i$ for $i=1,2$. I know $CP^1$  is a Riemann surface (and in particular a two dimensional real manyfold) considering the maps $\phi_1 :U_1 \rightarrow C :[(z_1,z_2)] \rightarrow z_2/z_1$ and $\phi_2 :U_2 \rightarrow C :[(z_1,z_2)] \rightarrow z_1/z_2$ where $U_1$ consists of classes in which the first component is different from zero and anagolously $U_2$. But I was not able to induce using these maps a map between $CP^1$ and $CP^1$. It should be easy but I don't see it...

Comment: $CP^1$ is usually looked at and modelled as the Riemann sphere. Does it make more sense if you look at it that way?

Comment: Yes it does. So I suppose I have to apply a diffeomorphism between $CP^1$ and the Riemann surface before applying the polynomial. Could this make the game? I define $F : U_1 \rightarrow C \cup \infty : [(1,z)] \rightarrow z$ and $G :U_2 \rightarrow C \cup \infty : [(z,1)] \rightarrow 1/z$. These two functions glue together I guess doing what I need?

Comment: I have no idea what you need, didn't look at the pdf. How does the function in question look?

Comment: It's so simple that is even not defined. Two complex polynomials through their rations induce a function from $CP^1$ to $CP^1$, I have to understand how... just to understand the problem not even to solve it.. :)

Comment: Ah. Do you know that a meromorphic function on an open subset $U\subset\mathbb{C}$ is a (holomorphic) map to the Riemann sphere $\widehat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$? Then you only need to consider a neighbourhood of $\infty$, and there you look at $\dfrac{p(1/z)}{q(1/z)}$ in a neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the help :) So let me understand. Your last answer shows how to use a complex polynomial to define a holomorphic map from the Riemann sphere to the Riemann sphere. Is it right? But my problem is understanding the role of $CP^1$ as I described it in my first post. Is it true that I have to consider the diffeomofism between $CP^1$ and the Riemann sphere using the functions $F$ and $G$ that I wrote before in order to make this connection?

Comment: If you insist, use the diffeomorphism $[(z_1,z_2)]\mapsto z_1/z_2$ for $z_2 \neq 0$, and $[(z,0)]\mapsto \infty$. But thinking in terms of $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}$ is easier.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot :) .... I think I'll follow your suggestion, I simply wanted to understand this diffeomorphism, it doesn't mean I'm gonna use it :)... I think the formula you wrote is the same one constructed by me using F and G before.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been resolved by Daniel Fischer in the comments.